# Como declaro um inteiro com capacidade de armazenamento de 30 bytes?

Tags: c

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Sei que o interpretador da linguagem Python é feito em C. Em Python as variáveis numéricas não tem restrição de tamanho, ou seja, quanto mais formos acrescentando valor a variável, mais a variável aumenta a quantidade de bytes para que seja possessível armazenar o valor. Como eu faço em C para declarar, por exemplo, variáveis com 30 bytes de tamanho para armazenar inteiros ou números flutuantes?

Comment: Em essência tem que fazer algo bem complexo para administrar isso. Armazenar é a parte fácil, o problema é operar neste valor. Mas pode ser que tenha outra solução para o que precisa.

Comment: Se quer trabalhar em algo já feito pode utilizar a biblioteca [*GMP*](https://gmplib.org/), senão só implementando manualmente, mas como o @Maniero indicou não é coisa fácil.